# In a PHP extension, is there a way to get a callback for every method call made in a php script?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I'd like my extension to get a callback for any method called in a php script.  Including native methods especially.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could look up in the definition for `array_map` or any other extension function that accepts a callable/callback as an argument on how to deal with callbacks.